# Perspective incorrect in GLFW3

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw, glm-math

I am trying to make a 3D game in Linux in C++ with GLFW and glad. But proper 3D perspective is not correctly working and I can't work out why.

This should draw an orange triangle which gets smaller when you get further away and bigger when you get closer, but it never changes size and only ends up reaching the clipping planes and disappearing.

Plus, if this helps, if I have the triangle at a z of 0 I can't see it even if I move back or forth.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "glad/glad.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
#include "glm/glm.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp"


// Vertex Shader source code
const char* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
"\n"
"uniform mat4 model;\n"
"uniform mat4 view;\n"
"uniform mat4 proj;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   gl_Position = model * view * proj * vec4(aPos, 1.0);\n"
"}\0";
//Fragment Shader source code
const char* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   FragColor = vec4(0.8f, 0.3f, 0.02f, 1.0f);\n"
"}\n\0";

int SCREEN_WIDTH=800;
int SCREEN_HEIGHT=600;

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    SCREEN_WIDTH=width;
    SCREEN_HEIGHT=height;
}

int main()
{
    // Initialize GLFW
    glfwInit();

    // Tell GLFW what version of OpenGL we are using
    // In this case we are using OpenGL 3.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    // Tell GLFW we are using the CORE profile
    // So that means we only have the modern functions
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // Create a GLFWwindow object of width by height pixels, naming it "3D C++"
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "3D C++", NULL, NULL);
    // Error check if the window fails to create
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    // Introduce the window into the current context
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    //Load GLAD so it configures OpenGL
    gladLoadGL();
    // Specify the viewport of OpenGL in the Window
    // In this case the viewport goes from x = 0, y = 0, to x = width, y = height
    glViewport(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);


    // Create Vertex Shader Object and get its reference
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    // Attach Vertex Shader source to the Vertex Shader Object
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    // Compile the Vertex Shader into machine code
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    // Create Fragment Shader Object and get its reference
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    // Attach Fragment Shader source to the Fragment Shader Object
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    // Compile the Vertex Shader into machine code
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    // Create Shader Program Object and get its reference
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    // Attach the Vertex and Fragment Shaders to the Shader Program
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    // Wrap-up/Link all the shaders together into the Shader Program
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    // Delete the now useless Vertex and Fragment Shader objects
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);



    // Vertices coordinates
    GLfloat vertices[] =
    {
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Lower left corner
        -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Lower right corner
        0.0f, 1.73205080757f, 0.0f // Upper corner
    };

    // Create reference containers for the Vartex Array Object and the Vertex Buffer Object
    GLuint VAO, VBO;

    // Generate the VAO and VBO with only 1 object each
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    // Make the VAO the current Vertex Array Object by binding it
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    // Bind the VBO specifying it's a GL_ARRAY_BUFFER
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    // Introduce the vertices into the VBO
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Configure the Vertex Attribute so that OpenGL knows how to read the VBO
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    // Enable the Vertex Attribute so that OpenGL knows to use it
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // Bind both the VBO and VAO to 0 so that we don't accidentally modify the VAO and VBO we created
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glm::vec3 cam = glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(cam,glm::vec3(cam.x,cam.y,cam.z-3.0f),glm::vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
    //view = glm::translate(view, cam);
    glm::mat4 proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)SCREEN_WIDTH/(float)SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);



    // Main while loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS) {
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
        }
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_DOWN) == GLFW_PRESS) cam.z-=0.01f;
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_UP) == GLFW_PRESS) cam.z+=0.01f;
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_LEFT) == GLFW_PRESS) cam.x-=0.01f;
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_RIGHT) == GLFW_PRESS) cam.x+=0.01f;
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_Q) == GLFW_PRESS) cam.y-=0.01f;
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_E) == GLFW_PRESS) cam.y+=0.01f;
        std::cout << cam.x << " , " << cam.y << " , " << cam.z << std::endl;

        model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        view = glm::lookAt(cam,glm::vec3(cam.x,cam.y,cam.z-3.0f),glm::vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
        //view = glm::translate(view, cam);
        proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)SCREEN_WIDTH/(float)SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        int modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
        int viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
        int projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "proj");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(proj));

        glClearColor(0.07f, 0.13f, 0.17f, 1.0f);
        // Clean the back buffer and assign the new color to it
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        // Tell OpenGL which Shader Program we want to use
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        // Bind the VAO so OpenGL knows to use it
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        // Draw the triangle using the GL_TRIANGLES primitive
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        // Swap the back buffer with the front buffer
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        // Take care of all GLFW events
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // Delete all the objects we've created
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    // Delete window before ending the program
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    // Terminate GLFW before ending the program
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try `gl_Position = proj * (view * (model * vec4(aPos, 1.0)));`

Comment: That has done something.

Comment: I thought it was still broken for a bit but that's just because I was using WASD and forwards and backwards is flipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing:
`gl_Position = model * view * proj * vec4(aPos, 1.0)));`

to:
`gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);`

worked.
Bit odd, but thanks user253751 !

Comment: Not odd - multiplying matrices in a different order doesn't give the same answer.

Comment: Its just that I saw exactly this on an online tutorial, so they must have changed it latter.